# Is it possible to define a function within an indexable type interface in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'd like to define the following:

```
export interface IValidationContextIndex {
    [validationContextKey: string]: ValidationContext;
    getValidationContexts(): Array<ValidationContext>;
}
```

This way I can get an object that adheres to the `IValidationContextIndex` interface and call `getValidationContexts` on it.

However VSCode is NOT HAPPY with this type of definition.  Is it possible to do this in an interface or do I need something like:

```
class cache {
    constructor(public index: IValidationContextIndex ) {};
    getValidationContexts() {return Object.value(<any> index)}
}
```

Comment: Why does TS not like your definition? Seems to work for me.

Comment: @TylerSebastian Depends on you definition for `ValidationContext` with `class ValidationContext {private x!: string}` it will not work for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that typescripts would prefer that the index signature be consistent will ALL declared members. Since you can use the index to access the `getValidationContexts` member as well and it's type will not be `ValidationContext`.

You can make the index signature consistent will the defined members, but it's not ideal as you will need to narrow the return type:

```
export interface IValidationContextIndex {
    [validationContextKey: string]: ValidationContext | (() => Array<ValidationContext>);
    getValidationContexts(): Array<ValidationContext>;
}
```

A way to get around this restriction is to use an intersection type:

```
type IValidationContextIndex = {
    [validationContextKey: string]: ValidationContext;
} & {
    getValidationContexts(): Array<ValidationContext>;
}
```

But objects of this type can't be created directly, for the same index incompatibility reason. You would need to create the objects using `Object.assign` :

```
let o : IValidationContextIndex = Object.assign({ a: new ValidationContext() }, {
    getValidationContexts(): Array<ValidationContext> {
        return Object.values(this)as any
    }
});
```

Or using a type assertion:

```
let o : IValidationContextIndex = {
    getValidationContexts(): Array<ValidationContext> {
        return Object.values(this)as any
    }
} as IValidationContextIndex;
```

Comment: Dam - You're like the Bruce Lee of Typescript!  Thanks!

Comment: @Ole :)) 10x. I'm just a slightly obsessed fan :P